# Avro C# generate classes using types defined across multiple schema files

Tags: c#, avro

I'm using the [Apache.Avro](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Apache.Avro) package to generate some C# from some Avro schemas. I have separate schemas that share common building blocks, like Enum definitions.

I'm having an issue where references to common shared schemas don't resolve properly.

Here's the model, defined in one file:

```json
{
    "name": "MyModel",
    "namespace": "My.Model",
    "type": "record",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "Planet",
            "type": "My.Model.PlanetEnum",
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's the definition for the `My.Model.PlanetEnum`, which is to be shared across multiple models:

```json
{
  "name": "PlanetEnum",
  "namespace": "My.Model",
  "type": "enum",
  "symbols": [
    "Earth",
    "Mars"
  ]
}
```

Here's the C# I'm using to generate the schemas:

```cs
        var codeCompileUnit = new CodeGen
        {
            Schemas =
            {
/* generation fails even if I include the enum definition inline here
                Schema.Parse("""
{
  "name": "PlanetEnum",
  "namespace": "My.Model",
  "type": "enum",
  "symbols": [
    "Earth",
    "Mars"
  ]
}
"""),
*/
                Schema.Parse(schemaText)
            },
        }.GenerateCode();

        var stringWriter = new StringWriter(new StringBuilder());
        var provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("csharp");
        provider.GenerateCodeFromCompileUnit(codeCompileUnit, stringWriter, new CodeGeneratorOptions());
        var schemaCode = stringWriter.ToString();
        return schemaCode;
```

The error I get is:

```
Avro.SchemaParseException: Undefined name: My.Model.PlanetEnum at 'fields[0].type'
   at Avro.Schema.ParseJson(JToken jtok, SchemaNames names, String encspace)
   at Avro.RecordSchema.createField(JToken jfield, Int32 pos, SchemaNames names, String encspace)
   at Avro.RecordSchema.NewInstance(Type type, JToken jtok, PropertyMap props, SchemaNames names, String encspace)
   at Avro.NamedSchema.NewInstance(JObject jo, PropertyMap props, SchemaNames names, String encspace)
   at Avro.Schema.ParseJson(JToken jtok, SchemaNames names, String encspace)
   at Avro.Schema.Parse(String json, SchemaNames names, String encspace)
   at Avro.Schema.Parse(String json)
```

Comment: You should have one main schema and use INCLUDE to reference child schemas.  See : https://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_include.asp?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng thanks for your comment, but that's not relevant here, that's just a general XML syntax, this is Avro JSON (avsc)

Comment: Are you sure I'm not right?

Comment: @jdweng your comment is about a different markup language entirely and has nothing to do with `avro`, `avrogen`, or C# at all. Did you read my question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to generate the C# code by combining the two schemas like this:

```cs
    var combinedSchemaText = $"[{planetEnumSchemaText},{schemaText}]";
    var combinedSchema = Schema.Parse(combinedSchemaText);
```

The complete code that I used:

```cs
        public static void Main()
        {
            var schemaText = @"
            {
                ""name"": ""MyModel"",
                ""namespace"": ""My.Model"",
                ""type"": ""record"",
                ""fields"": [
                    {
                        ""name"": ""Planet"",
                        ""type"": ""My.Model.PlanetEnum""
                    }
                ]
            }";

            var code = GenerateCSharpCodeCombined(schemaText);
            Console.WriteLine("Generated C# code:");
            Console.WriteLine(code);
        }

        private static string GenerateCSharpCodeCombined(string schemaText)
        {
            var planetEnumSchemaText = @"
            {
                ""name"": ""PlanetEnum"",
                ""namespace"": ""My.Model"",
                ""type"": ""enum"",
                ""symbols"": [
                ""Earth"",
                ""Mars""
                ]
            }";

            var combinedSchemaText = $"[{planetEnumSchemaText},{schemaText}]";
            var combinedSchema = Schema.Parse(combinedSchemaText);

            var codeGen = new CodeGen();
            codeGen.Schemas.Add(combinedSchema);

            var codeCompileUnit = codeGen.GenerateCode();

            var stringWriter = new StringWriter(new StringBuilder());
            var provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("csharp");
            provider.GenerateCodeFromCompileUnit(codeCompileUnit, stringWriter, new CodeGeneratorOptions());
            var schemaCode = stringWriter.ToString();

            return schemaCode;
        }
```

Check it and let's see if this solves your problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. It will work for a single case, but I don't think this solves the problem properly because it has to be done for every top-level schema that references the enum building block. In other words, when we have a `MyOtherModel` that will also need the enum schema copied in. When you generate both, they will both generate the same enum, and you will have a conflict because you will have two enums of the same name defined in the same namespace (assuming your top level schemas have the same namespace)

Comment: Apologies if I didn't make that clear enough in the original question. I can edit it if you think it should be clearer.

Comment: Also, this gets increasingly complex when you have multiple subschemas in various separate files in a directory. It feels like Avro just doesn't have support for this natively in C#

Comment: @xandermonkey I understand what you trying to achieve, but this doesn't seem supported.  I think this is a similar problem: https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/issues/1127

Comment: Got it. That's unfortunate!

Comment: You should update your answer to link that in the answer, and I'll mark it as the answer. Even though it's not actually a solution, it's the closest thing that exists as an answer, so you should get the reputation.